# This math string doesn't work! Batch

Tags: variables, batch-file, math

I'm making a profit system based on wages, workers, etc. but, it doesn't work! Here's the code:

```
:Business_Type
cls
echo What type of business do you want to own?
echo The options are: coal, oil, iron, steel, wine, copper or ore
set /p business=
if %Gametype% equ TUTORIAL goto Tutorial_D1
if %Gametype% equ GAME goto STM_GAME
:CALCULATE
if %business% equ coal set base_incomePP=15 && set maintanenceB=100 && minwage=7
if %business% equ oil set base_incomePP=25 && set maintanenceB=115 && minwage=8
if %business% equ iron set base_incomePP=15 && set maintanenceB=145 && minwage=9
if %business% equ steel set base_incomePP=20 && set maintanenceB=165 && minwage=10
if %business% equ wine set base_incomePP=100 && set maintanenceB=200 && minwage=6
if %business% equ copper set base_incomePP=20 && set maintanenceB=145 && minwage=9
if %business% equ ore set base_incomePP=10 && set maintanenceB=100 && minwage=8
set MAINTAINSPEC=maintanenceB
set workers=50
set maxwage=7000
set wages=minwage
set maintainence=MAINTAINSPEC
set /a "total_wages=wages*workers"
set base_incomePW=10
set /a "income=base_incomePP*workers-total_wages-maintainence"
set day=1
set money=1000
cls
echo Money: %money% Income: %income% Wages: %wages%
pause
```

The problem is the income, the income calculation freezes after it multiplies `workers` with `base_incomePP`
I also tried splitting it up:

```
set /a "income=base_incomePP*workers"
set /a "income=income-total_wages"
set /a "income=income-maintainence"
cls
echo Money: %money% Income: %income% Wages: %wages%
pause
```

But it still freezes the calculation after it multiplies `workers` by `base_incomePP`. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to "set" minwage.

`if %business% equ coal set base_incomePP=15 && set maintanenceB=100 && set minwage=7`

And you need to reference a variable.

`set wages=%minwage%`

Comment: also `set /a wages=minwage` works (for numbers). And one `&` is enough (`&&` means "if previous command was successful then")

Comment: I used `&&` because of that reason.

Comment: Rookie mistakes! Thanks, I will remember how to code next time XD!